# MySQL CONCAT return null with two valid strings

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

I'm working on a MySQL function that should function as the `JSON_MERGE` (my deployment server is MySQL 5.5.51) and I'm getting a null return from the `CONCAT` MySQL function. A Piece of code to explain better:

```
    IF(v_json is not null AND v_fianlJson is not null) THEN
        return CONCAT(v_fianlJson, v_json);
    END IF;
```

I fail to understand why the result of this concat is null. Can you see what I'm missing?

I'm pasting below the full function. In my local environment (MySQL 5.5.42) this function works, with the same data.

```
USE `o2stag`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `getApplicationData`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `stag`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getApplicationData`(pApplication_id INT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE v_json TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE v_finalJson TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT 
        id, data INTO v_id, v_json
    FROM application_data 
    WHERE application_id = pApplication_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1; 

    WHILE (v_id is not null) DO

        IF(v_finalJson is null AND v_json is not null) THEN
            SET v_finalJson = v_json;       
        ELSE

            IF(v_finalJson is not null AND v_json is not null) THEN               
                SET v_finalJson = CONCAT(CONCAT(LEFT(v_finalJson, CHAR_LENGTH(v_finalJson) -1), ''),',', SUBSTRING(v_json, 2));             
            END IF;

        END IF;
        #---------------------------------------------------------------
        # Just to control the logic cursor
        IF(SELECT 1=1 FROM application_data WHERE application_id = pApplication_id AND id > v_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) THEN
            SELECT id, data INTO v_id, v_json FROM application_data 
            WHERE application_id = pApplication_id 
                AND id > v_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;      
        ELSE
            SET v_id = null;
            SET v_json = '';
       END IF;

    END WHILE;      

    RETURN v_finalJson;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are the exact data types of the involved variables?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález both are TEXT. I saw the typo in the variable name but it is the same in all the function. It's not a typo problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (SQLFiddle is no longer functional so I don't know how to share it). I suspect you cannot reproduce it either with that bit of code and the issue only happens in your complete function because the error is somewhere else. I suggest you add an `ELSE` clause anyway just for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

We had to recreate the function using `group_concat`, it saved a lot of queries in the database. For `group_concat` there is a limit of chars the function can concat, I didn't look how to set this limit for the `concat` function, but I believe there must be a way to set it as well.

The new function:

```
USE `stag`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `getApplicationData`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `o2stag`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getApplicationData`(pApplication_id INT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    # creates a full json object
    DECLARE v_finalJson TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    SET group_concat_max_len = 9999999999;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('{',Json,'}') INTO v_finalJson FROM(
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT( SUBSTRING( data, 2, LENGTH( data ) - 2 ) SEPARATOR ',') AS Json
        FROM stag.application_data 
        WHERE application_id = pApplication_id) AS TJoin;

    RETURN v_finalJson;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CONCAT_WS solved a similar problem for me. It seems to handle nulls differently to CONCAT.

```
CONCAT_WS('', v_fianlJson, v_json)
```